# Changing orientation with onClick android

Tags: java, android, orientation, buttonclick

I am trying to implement a button click to be able to change the orientation of the activity however, it is going into landscape mode but not going back to portrait.

```java
if(!state){
    setRequestedOrientation(MainActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
else {
    setRequestedOrientation(MainActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
state = !state;
```

What I read was to, have state = false, when the button is pressed, change the orientation, then state is set as true, at this point if the button is pressed again the activity will change back to landscape.

I also read about using switch? But I tried implementing that but didn't go so well so I tried this method.

**Edit**

I've implemented using getting the surface rotation and they are able to pick up the rotation either being 0 or 90

```java
if (orientation==Surface.ROTATION_0)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "going to landscape", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setRequestedOrientation(MainActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}
else if (orientation==Surface.ROTATION_90)
{
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "going to portrait", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setRequestedOrientation(MainActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
}
```

However, as the activity goes into landscape and the toast is shown, when I try to go back into portrait the toast does show "going to portrait" but the setRequestOrientation does not execute. What seems to be the issue?

Comment: Means on button click you want to change orientation but its did't happen.

Comment: When the orientation is changed, the activity is recreated. So, I guess, after you change the orientation, value of `state` is `false` again. Check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an activity is rotated it is destroyed and re-created. When this happens you are going to be losing the value of 'state'. This will result in you never hitting the other option as it is always being returned back to the original option.

Look at onSaveInstanceState() [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29).

You can then access the bundle in the onCreate() method to retrieve the value.

Comment: I've looked at the onSaveInstanceState()
I'm not sure 100% but what I gathered is that I need to use outStatu.putBoolean("state", state) and with the onRestoreInstanceState it is savedInstanceState.getBoolean("state");
Is this the right direction?

Comment: It sure is. If you don't want to implement onRestoreInstanceState you can check to see if the savedInstanceState bundle is null inside onCreate(). If the bundle is not null, just load the boolean there.

Comment: Check the parameters here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)

Comment: setRequestedOrientation(MainActivity.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
This is the correct code to change to portrait isnt it? For some reason it will never go into portrait mode. I've even forced landscape mode to try this code but it is not changing. Very weird.